# How can I get the random images displaying to not repeat?

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, repeat

I'm making a generic app using Android Studio; I want to display 4 random images from my array but don't know how prevent an image repeating.

```
public class answerScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4;
Random r;
Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3,
        R.drawable.img4,
        R.drawable.img5,
        R.drawable.img6,
        R.drawable.img7
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer_screen);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);

    r = new Random();

    //diplay random image
    imageView.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);
    imageView2.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);
    imageView3.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);
    imageView4.setImageResource(images[r.nextInt(images.length)]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate 4 random ints in range `[0,images.length)` and store them in an array like:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randInts [] = r.ints(0, images.length).distinct().limit(4).toArray();
```

and use that array to set image resources:

```
imageView.setImageResource(images[randInts[0]]);
imageView2.setImageResource(images[randInts[1]]);
imageView3.setImageResource(images[randInts[2]]);
imageView4.setImageResource(images[randInts[3]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shuffling the array and then getting the first four items is an easy way to do this.
An easy example:

```
Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
Collections.shuffle(intList);
intList.toArray(intArray);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

I got this from: https://www.journaldev.com/32661/shuffle-array-java